# Insert/create data using belongsTo Relation in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Phone BelongsTo User. Now how i insert phone & user data both through belongsTo Relationship & auto get user_id foreign key in phone table. Here I try this code but not work.

```
$phoneData = $request->get('phone');
$userData = $request->get('name');
$phone->user()->create($userData);
$phone->create($phoneData);
```

[Here is in form input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UleaH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$userData  = $request->get('name');
$phoneData = $request->get('phone');

$user = User::create($userData);
$user->phones()->save(new Phone($phoneData));
```

Of course you'll need to define the relationship on the User model as well:

```
// \App\User.php
public function phones()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Phone::class);
}
```

Comment: Yes this is work but i want to do this reverse way through belongsTo method (Phone Model) not hasMany .

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a phone without an user, it's not recommended because the foreign key constraint, that you must have in your database, won't let you..

```
$userData  = $request->get('name');
$phoneData = $request->get('phone');

$phone = new Phone();
$phone->user()->associate(User::create($userData));
$phone->save();
```

Maybe you are looking for something like this...

for updating..

```
$phone = isset($phoneData['id']) 
   ? Phone::where('id', $phoneData['id'])->first() : new Phone(); 
$phone->user()->associate(User::firstOrCreate(
  ['email' =>$userData['email']], .... extra data from user));
$phone->save();
```

Comment: thats mean insertion not possible through belongsTo relationship ?  what about update process ?? . Thanks for your info